# Unary operator negation in C not working

Tags: c, bit-shift, unary-operator

I am trying to flip bits of a number using the unary operator ~ in C but the function seems to be returning nothing. The code i have made is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int flipBits(int n) {
    return ~n;
}
void convertbinary(int n)
{
    while(n>0)
    {
        printf("%d",n%2);
        n=n/2;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n=21;
    int x=flipBits(n);
    convertbinary(x);
}
```

The output for the above code is nothing. It return -22.
What i am trying to accomplish eventually is to change the MSB of a given number to 0. The solution i came up with was

```
n&&((n^~(n)>>1)
```

So, basically XOR-ing the number with its inverse to get all 1's and then right shifting to make the MSB 0 and AND-ing with the original number to make the MSB of the oriiginal number 0. 
For example

```
if n=21 i.e. 10101; ~n=01010; n^~n=11111; (n^~n)>>1 = 01111; n&&((n^~n)>>1)=00101
```

Please correct me if i am doing anything wrong. Thank you.

Comment: It prints nothing because the unary negation of 21 is a negative number. Thus `while (n > 0)` is never true.

Comment: There is a big difference between boolean && and bitwise &.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't print anything because the negation of 21 is a negative number.

```
21 = 0000000...010101
```

Flipping every bit yields:

```
1111111...101010
```

So, the loop condition (`n > 0`) is never true. You probably want `while (n != 0)` instead:

```
void convertbinary(int n)
{
    while (n != 0)
    {
        printf("%d",n%2);
        n=n/2;
    }
}
```

Or you can keep using `n > 0` and make `n` an `unsigned`.

Comment: @rawatadit: You might want to handle 0 explicitly, otherwise `convertbinary()` will print nothing when you probably want it to print `0`.